# The number of elements of intersection of $aH ∩ Ha^2$

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group. Let H be a normal subgroup of G. Assume
$\operatorname{ord}(G) = 24$ and $\operatorname{ord}(H) = 4.$ 
Let $a \in G$ such that $a \notin H.$

(a) What can you say about the number of elements of $aH ∩ Ha^2$?

(b) How about $aH ∩ Ha^3?$

Comment: I know that if a /∈ G, then aH is a coset disjoint from H. Looking at the order of G and H, I should use that to find the numbers of right cosets. But I really don't know how, also what is a^2, and a^3 here!

Comment: You've got two cosets of $H$, so they're either equal or disjoint. The question just comes down to asking if they're equal, which is equivalent to $a$ and $a^2$ (resp. $a^3$) being in the same coset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H$ is normal, $aH = Ha$.

(a) Assume there is an element $x \in aH \cap Ha^2$. Then $x = ha = ka^2 \in Ha \cap Ha^2$, for some $h,k \in H$. Therefore $a = k^{-1} h \in H$ (because $H$ is a subgroup), contradiction. Conclusion: $aH \cap Ha^2$ is empty.

(b) By the same reasoning, if $aH \cap Ha^3$ is nonempty, then $ha = ka^3$ for some $h, k \in H$ and therefore $a^2 = k^{-1} h \in H$. In this case, $Ha^3 = Ha = aH$ and therefore $aH \cap Ha^2 = aH$ has $\mathrm{ord}(H) = 4$ elements. Otherwise, if $a^2 \not\in H$, then it's empty.